UITableView Suppress checkboxs on left when editing
I have a UITableView with multiple-selection during editing. The UITableViewCells have no Accessory or EditingAccessory configured in the Storyboard.
When I select a row and enter Edit mode, the rows all get a new circle icon on the left, with the row content shifted to the right. This is some sort of checkbox selection indictor by the looks.
I can't find any way to suppress this. I don't want a selection indicator on the left, and especially don't want the content shifted right.
editingStyleForRowAt returns .none
accessoryType is set to .none
What's causing this indicator to appear, and how can I suppress it?

What value have you specified for allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing?  If it is true then you get selection checkboxes.

It's set to True. I want to allow multiple selection (by tapping on additional rows) but don't want the checkboxes. Or, more to the point, don't want my content to shift right to accommodate the checkboxes.

If you set it to true then you get the checkboxes.

OK, thanks @Paulw11. It sounds like I can't have multiple selection allowed with the checkboxes appearing. Oh well!

While technically it's not suppressing the checkboxes, an alternative is a small hack to give the appearance of doing so. I've added a further answer to this question, which shows how to hide the checkboxes and out-dent your content. The appearance is then the same as if the checkboxes not being displayed.
